# Play 2 - Can't return Json object in Response

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to do some RESTFull Web service POC using Play 2.1.3

I have the following class:

```
case class Student(id: Long,firstName: String,lastName: String)
```

Now I would like to create RESTfull URI which will get Json serialised Student POJO and return the same POJO in response.

```
implicit val studentReads = Json.reads[Student]
implicit val studentWrites = Json.writes[Student]


def updateStudent = Action(parse.json){
  request=>request.body.validate[Student].map{
    case xs=>Ok(xs)}.recoverTotal{
      e => BadRequest("Detected error:"+ JsError.toFlatJson(e))
    }
  }
```

But I'm getting compilation Error -

```
Cannot write an instance of entities.Student to HTTP response. Try to define a 
     Writeable[entities.Student]
```

I just provided `Writes[A]` as an implicit variable.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think the problem is that the Ok() method cannot figure out the `Student` needs to be transformed to json, as the arguments to Ok() may vary.

1. You may return an `Ok(Json.toJson(xs))`
2. You may explicitly point the desired type: `Ok(xs: JsValue)`

And be sure all implicits are in scope

Comment: Kept getting "Define writable" errors and Json.toJson gets rid of the errors. Thank you!